# Binary + Operator Overloading c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am just learning on C++ so any help provided would be great. I am trying to overload the binary operator + in my code: Here is my implementation.

**The compiler I am using is Xcode 6.1 on Mac OS X.**

I am getting a compilation error that the copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted where i use the + operator in the main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person{

private:
string name;
int age;
double height;

public:
Person(string n="Haroon", int a=23, double h=72.1){
    this->name = n;
    this->age = a;
    this->height = h;
};

int getAge() const { return this->age; }
double getHeight() const { return this->height; }
string getName() const { return this->name; }

void setHeight(double x){
    this->height = x;
}

Person operator+ (const Person &rhs){

    string a = this->getName();
    string b = rhs.getName();

    string name = a+b;

    int c = max(this->getAge(),rhs.getAge());
    int d = max(this->getHeight(),rhs.getHeight());

    Person p(name,c,d);
    return p;
}

~Person(){};
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

Person a("Abc",1,2);
Person b("Def",5,65);

Person n;
n = a+b;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: With what compiler ? Also, usually you should implement `operator+=` as a member, and `operator+` as a free functions calling `+=`

Comment: @quantdev i am using xcode on mac

Comment: Please post a minimal but *complete* code sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: @juanchopanza This is the entire code in my file

Comment: Are you including <string> and "using std" somewhere? Otherwise add include statement and replace all string with std::string.

Comment: yes i am including the lib string and std

Comment: That is the entire code in your file, yet you claim to be including lib string and std (whatever that means.) Your code doesn't reproduce the problem it one includes `<string>` and uses `std::string``.

Comment: FWIW I run your code in Visual Studio and it complied without errors (adding the necessary include and using statement)

Comment: @juanchopanza I have edited my code to include the libraries like in my original code. The error still remains

Comment: @user199421 I am already doing that and still am getting an error on xcode

Comment: So it seems like compiler doesn't produce assignment operator for whatever reason. Why don't you implement it yourself and see if it will be stepped in? (`Person & operator=(const Person & rhs) { if(this != &rhs){ ... } return *this;`)

Comment: See here: http://ideone.com/aCft5U

Comment: @d453 you are right. Have to overload the operator = to get this right

Answer (score -1):

1. The reason is here:

   Person n;    // You are calling the default constructor. You will get a Person("Haroon", 23, 72.1)

   n = a + b;   // You are calling an assignment operator which you didn't overload
2. C++ has default constructor, convert constructor and copy constructor.

   ```
   [~/testing/constructor]$ cat main.cpp

   #include <iostream>

   class A
   {
   public:

   A()      : value(0) { std::cout << "Default " << value << std::endl; }
   A(int a) : value(a) { std::cout << "Convert " << value << std::endl; }
   A(const A& other) : value(other.value) { std::cout << "Copy    " << value << std::endl; }

   private:
       int value;
   };

   int main()
   {
       A x;
       A y(10);
       A z = y;
       A w(x);
   }


   [~/testing/constructor]$ ./run
   Default 0
   Convert 10
   Copy    10
   Copy    0
   ```

   Here x is constructed by default, y is convert. Note that both `A z = y;` and `A w(x);` are copy constructor. They are exactly the same!! But your `n = a + b;` is an assign operator.
3. Using initialization than assignment in constructor. the `: value(0)` is the initialize. This is an idiom in Scott Meyers "Effective C++" book.
4. The `this->` can be omitted in C++ if you are writing member functions of a class. The variable you are using is the member variable of class or function local variable or global variable. (If the name has conflict, variable using priority local > member > global ) eg.

   ```
   [~/testing/var]$ cat main.cpp
   #include <iostream>

   int a;

   class A
   {
   public:
       A()      : a(0) {}
       A(int x) : a(x) {}
       ~A() {}

       void f() { int a = 9; std::cout << a << std::endl; }
   private:
       int a;
   };

   int main()
   {
       A x(5);
       x.f();
   }
   [~/testing/var]$ ./run
   9
   ```

For your class, the formal C++ format I would write like this:

```
class Person{

public: // constructor & destructor
    Person(string n="Haroon", int a=23, double h=72.1)
        : name(n)
        , age(a)
        , height(h)
    {
    }
    Person(const Person& other)
        : name(other.name)
        , age(other.age)
        , height(other.height)
    {
    }

public: // operators

    Person& operator=(const Person& other)
    {
        if (&other == this) return *this;  // Such as using as "a = a"

        name   = other.name;
        age    = other.age;
        height = other.height;

        return *this;
    }

    Person operator+(const Person& other)
    {
        string n = name + other.name;  // You don't have to use other.getName() because C++ private variable is accessible by self class and friend class
        age    a = max(age, other.age);
        height h = max(height, other.height);

        return Person(n, a, h);
    }
public: // setter & getter

    int    getAge()    const { return age;    }
    double getHeight() const { return height; }
    string getName()   const { return name;   }

    void setHeight(double x) { height = x; }

private:
    string name;
    int    age;
    double height;

};
```

Comment: Am I missing something or assignment operator should be generated by compiler in this case?

Comment: @BigTailWolf yes that is my question as well. As witnessed in some of the compilers the code is running smooth

Comment: @stud91 I rewrite your code in my change of the answer, may some small problem with the max() function not added. But that's the most formal way of C++ code that shouldn't be denied by any compiler and OS. Hope it can help you.

Comment: @BigTailWolf I haven't checked your code but in my code if I overload the assignment operator then it works.

Comment: @stu91 since you are new to C++, I recommend you follow "Effective C++" idioms

Comment: This is a very long winded wrong answer. There is no need to overload the assignment operator.